# Can I merge multiple materials into one?

Tags: materials

I've downloaded and imported to blender 3d models of buildings **as one object** from open street map. Almost every wall of the buildings imported with it's own material and it will take me ages to texture them seperately. Can I merge some of the materials? The only thing I can come up with is selecting each building on edit mode and assign it each time to the same material, which is also would take me ages to do. Any better idea?

Answer (score 3):

If I got what you ask, you can make material links from all objects to one: all will get last object's material assigned.

It works like this: select all object but one, and then select that last one object too (it will be the "active" object in the selection).

Then use the menu "make links => materials" (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and choose "materials". See this image below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This solution is a bit late but it can help people from future with similar problem.

first, you go to the outliner and pick "Blender File" view.
[image: Outliner]

then open materials, where you will see all the materials this project use.

To use remap materials pick one of those you want to merge, then right-click and pick "remap users". There, under "new ID" pick your target material. Then you can select all the materials you want to merge and just click "OK", it remembers last operation. [image]

Done! Now all objects that were using extra materials use the one you chose. You can delete unused materials and live happily ever after.